# Why does Transmission no longer open a port with Upnp enabled?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission, upnp

Transmission was working well until about a week ago, and then quit opening a port.
Upnp is enabled in both the router and Transmission.
All ports show stealth mode by grc.
Had a friend check Transmission on his computer and he also found it no longer opens a port.
Has ubuntu done something that requires action in order to make upnp work in Transmission?

Comment: I have the same issue. Clicking on randomize port a couple of times in Transmission preferences will result in a "Port is open" status. But it won't do it automatically for some reason.